# How to set path to picture in folder in device in android appcelerator app

Tags: path, share, appcelerator

So I have app where I want to let users to share screenshot of score to facebook etc... I'm using SocialShare widget. In documentation it says to set path to image like this: "image:fileToShare.nativePath", but I'm not really sure how to set it. Another problem is that I need to share picture that has always different name, it saves screenshots with names like tia7828157.png,tia107997596.png... in folder in device internal memory in pictures/enigmania/ I'm new to appcelerator, so I dont know if there is something like wildcard I could use for this? Thanks for any help.

This is my code so far which I know is wrong, I know the widget works because it shares text without problem:

```
function shareTextWidget(e){
// share text status
var socialWidget=Alloy.createWidget('com.alcoapps.socialshare');
socialWidget.share({status:"Enigmania kvíz",androidDialogTitle:"hoho",image:test.png/pictures/enigmania});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should use **[Ti.Filesystem](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem)** class methods/properties to get the path of any file located on internal or external storage.
- Also aware of the permissions of reading storage on Android 6+. Use **[Storage Permissions](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-requestStoragePermissions)** before accessing any file on Android 6+.

Simple code snippet to create a directory on internal storage at this location: **pictures/enigmania** and then write an image file of captured view in this directory.

```
function shareTextWidget(e){
    var directory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'pictures/enigmania');
    !directory.exists() && directory.createDirectory();

    var fileToShare = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(directory.resolve(), 'screen.jpg');
    fileToShare.write($.SCREENSHOT_VIEW.toImage());    // write the blob image to created file

    var socialWidget=Alloy.createWidget('com.alcoapps.socialshare');
    socialWidget.share({status:"Enigmania kvíz",androidDialogTitle:"hoho",image:fileToShare.nativePath});
}
```

This code should work without any issues.

Note that **$.SCREENSHOT_VIEW** is the View ID for which you will take screenshot, so it depends on you how you maintain your View positions in order to capture correct screenshot, but point is to use **[Ti.UI.View toImage()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-toImage)** method to capture the screenshot of particular view.

Let me know if this works for you or not, else we can look into other methods by getting your exact requirements. Good Luck!!!!

Comment: Hello and thanks for reply. I wanted to test your code so I created folder in sd card with my test.png picture and updated my code like this  `var fileToShare = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file://', Ti.Filesystem. externalStorageDirectory, 'pictures/enigmania/test.png');
var fullPath = fileToShare.nativePath;
function shareTextWidget(e){
    // share text status
    var socialWidget=Alloy.createWidget('com.alcoapps.socialshare');
    socialWidget.share({status:"Enigmania kvíz",androidDialogTitle:"hoho",image:fileToShare});
 }` but It opens facebook and there is no image to share.

Comment: Try to find out the value of **fullPath** variable, if it seems correct then use this variable in widget's **image** attribute instead of **fileToShare** variable. Make sure that property **nativePath** is giving correct value and path spellings are correct. I will try to create such scenario at my end.

Comment: Ok so got the path of the picture from fullPath to be file:///appdata:/pictures/enigmania/test.png, but it still does not work with this path.

Comment: So i tried to find the path again with total commander installed in device and it gave me path "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Enigmania/test.png" which finally works so at least I know the module works. Problem is when I tried the same thing with emulator, the path was different. How is this supposed to work in my app if the path is different in every device?

Comment: I tried it yesterday for quite enough time and seems that Titanium cannot write anything on external storage, rather it always consider the internal memory of device as external memory. So for now, you can use my edited answer code.

Comment: Wow man thanks, it seems to be working. its awesome you took so much time to help me and for free. This means i can finally release my app I have been working on for 6 months. Again thanks million times.

Comment: Welcome! It also make us learn something new whenever we help others. Good Luck !!!!